# Why do i have this Android Studio Emulator screen problem?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

A few days ago, I downloaded Android Studio on Windows 10. I have a problem while launching the Virtual Device.
[Here you have a screenshot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQYvQ.png)

I tried diferent mobiles and deleted the device frame but the error still there, also, uninstalled the Android Studio and installed again with the last version and the plugins updated, but nothing.
Im wondering if someone knows how to solve this problem, maybe has something to do with the graffic card? (I have an RTX2070)

Thanks for your help.